# How to get attributes from an XML without transforming them into a single line

Tags: python, xml

~Python~

I've done some research for a while and I'm completely lost. I have an XML file, one of the attributes called notes has several lines in it such as

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<Document>
<XML_Body Version="13" Notes="Hello


World">
</XML_Body>
</Document>
```

When I get the attributes notes and print them out I get `Hello   World`. I need to keep the empty lines, is there a way to do that?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# Open pgm program
file = open("XMLfile.xml", 'r', encoding='ISO-8859-1')

# Get tree
pgmTree = ET.parse(file)
file.close()

# Get root
root = pgmTree.getroot()

# Get attributes
attributes = root.find("./XML_Body")

# Get notes
print(attributes.attrib["Notes"])
```

Ultimately all I want to do is get the note attributes, add something to them, and then save to a new file while keeping the same structure (empty lines and all).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Attribute values are normalized by the XML parser according to a number of rules and whitespace characters are changed to spaces.  From the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#AVNormalize):

> Note that if the unnormalized attribute value contains a character
> reference to a white space character other than space (#x20), the
> normalized value contains the referenced character itself (#xD, #xA or
> #x9). This contrasts with the case where the unnormalized value contains a white space character (not a reference), which is replaced
> with a space character (#x20) in the normalized value and also
> contrasts with the case where the unnormalized value contains an
> entity reference whose replacement text contains a white space
> character; being recursively processed, the white space character is
> replaced with a space character (#x20) in the normalized value.

So to keep newlines, attributes must use character references instead of actual newline characters:

```py
doc = '''\
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<Document>
<XML_Body Version="13" Notes="Hello&#xA;&#xA;&#xA;World">
</XML_Body>
</Document>
'''

import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
root = et.fromstring(doc)
attributes = root.find("./XML_Body")
print(attributes.attrib["Notes"])
```

```
Hello


World
```

Note that `ElementTree` itself writes an XML document with newlines in attributes correctly, so whatever originally generated the document may be broken:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import io

r = et.Element('Document')
r.text = '\n'
e = et.SubElement(r,'XML_Body')
e.attrib['Version'] = '13'
e.attrib['Notes'] = 'Hello\n\n\nWorld'
e.text = '\n'
e.tail = '\n'
t = et.ElementTree(r)

out = io.BytesIO()
t.write(out,encoding='ISO-8859-1',xml_declaration=True)
print(out.getvalue().decode('ISO-8859-1'))
```

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<Document>
<XML_Body Version="13" Notes="Hello&#10;&#10;&#10;World">
</XML_Body>
</Document>
```

Comment: Interesting. is there a way for the outcome to be

`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<Document>
<XML_Body Version="13" Notes="Hello&#13;&#10;&#13;&#10;&#13;&#10;World">
</XML_Body>
</Document>`

Comment: @JeycYelamo `\r` is `&#13;`, so `Hello\r\n\r\n\r\nWorld`

Comment: looks like I'm still getting &#10; despite changing it to \r\n

Comment: @Jeyc You’ll have to ask another question with a reproducible example. The above code with \r works for me.